# Impl design pattern in c++ in pytorch and xgboost

Tags: c++, pytorch, xgboost

In pytorch and xgboost, I noticed that there are a lot of files/classnames with Impl suffix. Can someone give me a hint if this is some sort of common design pattern in c++? What does Impl stand for? Implied? Implementation?

Examples are https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/ad3572a5dcaa23abe533f1a8d8a71775c6565460/c10/core/TensorImpl.h#L557

```
TensorImpl(
      Storage&& storage,
      DispatchKeySet,
      const caffe2::TypeMeta data_type,
      c10::optional<c10::Device>);

 public:
  TensorImpl(const TensorImpl&) = delete;
  TensorImpl& operator=(const TensorImpl&) = delete;
  TensorImpl(TensorImpl&&) = delete;
  TensorImpl& operator=(TensorImpl&&) = delete;
```

and
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/7a02facc9d5bb25b8cc7862a1d11d5071240c7c7/src/learner.cc#L1205

```
class LearnerImpl : public LearnerIO {
 public:
  explicit LearnerImpl(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<DMatrix> > cache)
      : LearnerIO{cache} {}
  ~LearnerImpl() override {
    auto local_map = LearnerAPIThreadLocalStore::Get();
    if (local_map->find(this) != local_map->cend()) {
      local_map->erase(this);
    }
  }
```

I tried to search around but did not find any good answer

Comment: Lookup the pimpl pattern : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl

Comment: Basically the pimpl pattern allows you to have a client facing class with no members (only a pointer to its implementation). This totally decouples the client code from the internal implementation details. It is condsired a compilation firewall, since all detailed header files needed for implementation will be invisble to the client code.